# Smooth curve through points with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, curve-fitting

I know that one can get smooth point connections with option `smooth` to `\addplot` that takes the previous and the next point into account, but this still *connects* all the points.

How can I draw a smooth curve through the points using `pgfplots` that are *not necessarily* connected? I'm not fully sure if this is correct, but I think I'm looking for "bezier curves" (correct me if wrong). To be clear: I do *not* want curve-fitting like one can do with `gnuplot`, just some "sloppy-smooth" connecting of points.

Example picture (not from my data!):

[image]

Here is my real data, they don't follow a known, analytical, mathematical function:

```
43  3.22
44  3.26
45  3.28
46  3.40
47  3.60
48  3.53
49  3.50
50  3.60
51  3.59
52  3.54
53  3.55
54  3.51
55  3.35
56  3.45
57  3.42
58  3.43
59  3.42
60  3.42
61  3.43
62  3.47
63  3.45
64  3.40
65  3.20
66  3.21
67  3.17
68  3.20
69  3.22
70  3.36
71  3.37
72  3.37
73  3.30
74  3.33
75  3.39
76  3.41
77  3.34
78  3.45
79  3.42
80  3.38
81  3.33
82  3.15
83  3.35
84  3.33
85  3.20
86  3.24
87  3.20
```

Comment: You are asking for the `hobby` package that Andrew Stacey created for TikZ.

Comment: @percusse: I agree, although hobby curves do go through all the specified points

Comment: @Jake oops, nice catch! It might still smoothen out though.

Comment: @FooBar: Could you edit your question to include an example of the data you want to smooth?

Comment: @Jake done. It does not follow any known mathematical function, however. Just some "random" points.

Comment: @percusse, can `hobby` be integrated directly in `pgfplots`?

Comment: Yes you can use TikZ commands inside the axis environments. But it might require a few modifications. I didn't test it.

Comment: @percusse, yes, it looks like (page 6), but it may not have the desired effect out of the box as the resulting curve is not a "function".

Comment: @alfC You don't `\addplot` it but rather `\draw` a TikZ path inside the axis environment. Jake's comment still holds though.

Comment: @Jake Since the last update, `hobby` can be used with `\addplot`.  However, I don't recommend it as it can double back on itself as alfC mentions.  (I added it because it was requested.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the `gnuplot` backend, put your points in a `file.dat`, and compile twice with `-shell-escape`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot +[no markers, raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
        plot 'file.dat' smooth sbezier;
    };
    \addplot +[only marks, raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
        plot 'file.dat' with points;
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone, but I like this solution most, since I'm using `gnuplot` already. But I upvoted all solutions, since they are all very good.

Answer (score 10):

One thing you could do is to calculate a LOESS smooth of the data. I don't know of a way to do this in LaTeX directly, but you could preprocess your data in R (which is free and useful to know, at any rate).

[image]

The following code reads the data from a file called `data.dat` and smoothes it using a span of `0.3` (i.e. it takes 30% of the data around each point into account for calculating a polynomial), and then writes it to a file called `smooth.dat`:

```
datapoints = read.delim('data.dat', header=F)
smooth=loess(datapoints$V2 ~ datapoints$V1, span=0.3)
write.table(data.frame(smooth$x,smooth$fitted), 'smooth.dat',sep='\t', quote=F, col.names=F, row.names=F)
```

Which you can then plot using:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks] table {../data.dat};
\addplot [red, smooth] table {../smooth.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your neat answer made me want to ask you a question about curve fitting with `pgfplots` and `gnuplot`.  [In my question here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340861/2288), is it possible to use `gnuplot` with `pgfplot` to get a fitting function through certain points then draw it?

Answer (score 7):

here is your data with a Bezier curve:

```
\documentclass{article}% run with xelatex
%\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}% for pdflatex --shell-escape
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=0.2,yunit=5}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(50,1)
\pstScalePoints(1,1){40 sub}{3 sub}
\psaxes[ticksize=0 5pt,Dy=0.2,Dx=10,Ox=40,Oy=3]{->}(0,0)(50,1)
\readdata\data{data0.dat}
\listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt,plotstyle=bezier]{43 3.22 \data}
\listplot[plotstyle=dots]{43 3.22 \data}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]