# Moving average with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a huge table of x,y data. Looks like this:

```
\addplot+[mark size=0.2]table[row sep=\\,x = add,y = mul]{add mul \\
2.   0.32 \\
6.0  0.23 \\
7.0  0.23 \\
8.0  0.13 \\
12.0 0.17 \\
23.0 0.14 \\
50.0 0.09 \\
...
```

However is you can see in the figure, the data is pretty dense. I just need to smooth out all the data points so the three different lines are visible distinctly from each others. The first thought that came to my mind is moving average. But I couldn't find how to do that with pgfplots.

[image: The figure]

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no prebuilt way of doing that, and it might be easier to do it in an external application (e.g. Python with `pandas`) and write out a `.csv` file. Could be possible with `pgfplots` alone, I don't know, if you're willing to try `lualatex` it would certainly be possible there (see e.g. https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109montijano.pdf for some examples of combining Lua and `pgfplots`).

Comment: I agree with TorbjørnT., that there is no built-in solution in PGFPlots. But at <http://opensourceforu.com/2016/06/plotting-with-latex/>, especially in section "Smoothing: an example of interacting with Scilab" (and resulting Figure 5) is described a workaround.

Comment: Just in case you, or anyone else seeing this, is interested: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109457/smooth-curve-through-points-with-pgfplots/109468#109468