# Plotting graph with piecewise linear interpolation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot a graph with piecewise linear interpolation from a CSV data file. Currently, I have only managed to plot a graph like the following one:

[image: Actual graph]

Here is my Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data_to_plot.csv}
A,B
0.011,0.0031
0.021,0.0046
0.021,0.0075
0.022,0.0171
0.022,0.0135
0.023,0.0191
0.099,0.0287
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=A, y=B, col sep=comma] {data_to_plot.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But, I want to plot the graph with piecewise linear interpolation like the following graph (drawn with MS Paint):

[image: Expected graph]

Here is the sample data (truncated):

```
A,B
0.0013,0.0061
0.0016,0.0046
0.0024,0.0057
0.0024,0.0036
0.0027,0.0064
0.0027,0.0047
0.0028,0.0068
...
...
0.9973,0.1514
0.9973,0.1421
0.9977,0.1169
0.9981,0.1289
0.9983,0.1896
0.9993,0.1335
0.9999,0.1547
```

So, my question is: how can I plot like this, possibly with customizing the X value *gaps* (it is 0.1 shown in the second figure)?

Comment: please provide complee small document, which we can compile, your table should be part of it  (included with `filecontents` package (for example as `\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
 x y
-2 7
-1 2
 0 5
 1 4
 2 8
\end{filecontents}`)

Comment: @Zarko: I have updated my question by adding a sample file content to the Latex code.

Comment: the main problem is number of `x` coordinates. see, if  `each nth point={<desired value>}` (adding to `table` options gives something close to what you after.

Comment: @Zarko: For plotting, I need to consider all `y` values, not just nth `y` values. Though I know how to calculate them mathematically, I cannot figure out how to do it in Latex.

Comment: than don't do this in LaTeX. it is not intended for this (well, you can use `lua`). use  programs like Mathematica or  Matlab and result use as new data. for your plot.

Comment: @Zarko: I thought, Latex has some package to do that without much code. Now I guess, I have to use other plotting tools to generate my intended graph and use it in Latex.

Comment: Is linear interpolation really the term you're looking for? Sounds like you're after a moving average (same as asked for in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310616/moving-average-with-pgfplots, though no answer there either)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am not sure about the exact term. That's why I have drawn a figure by MS Paint to demonstrate that. Looks like a similar question was asked three years ago! But in my case, I do not want a curved line in my graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by using external tools. In my case, I have used Python `matplotlib.pyplot` and `numpy` modules. I have generated my desired graph using these modules and exported it to a PDF file. Then I have used it in my Latex as a `figure`. Here is my Python code to achieve my goal:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_path = 'data_to_plot.csv'
x_title = 'A'
y_title = 'B'


def averaged_y_new(x_new, x, y):
    y_new = np.zeros(len(x_new), dtype=np.double)

    seg = x_new[1] - x_new[0]  # segment length between two adjacent x_new values
    ix_min = x_new[0] - (seg / 2.0)
    ix_max = ix_min + seg
    idx_x = 0  # iterated index of x array
    val_y = y[idx_x]  # y value of iterated index of x array
    for i in range(len(x_new)):
        sm = 0.0  # sum of y values
        nm = 0  # number of y values
        while idx_x < len(x) and ix_min <= x[idx_x] < ix_max:
            sm += y[idx_x]
            nm += 1
            idx_x += 1
        if nm != 0.0:
            y_new[i] = sm / nm  # average of y values
            val_y = y_new[i]
        else:
            y_new[i] = val_y
        ix_min = ix_max
        ix_max = ix_min + seg

    return y_new


def main():
    data = np.genfromtxt(data_path, dtype=np.double, delimiter=',', names=True)
    data.sort(order=[x_title])

    x = np.array(data[x_title])
    y = np.array(data[y_title])

    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)

    # plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

    x_new = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)
    y_new = averaged_y_new(x_new, x, y)

    plt.ylim(0, 0.5)
    plt.plot(x_new, y_new, '-bo')

    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig('graph.pdf')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above Python code generates the following graph:

[image: Achieved graph]