# Texstudio compile using -shell

Tags: texstudio, gnuplot

I want to create [this graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109468/127401) in Texstudio. However, I have no clue about how to compile gnuplot using -shell-escape. If someone could help, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to `Options`->`Configure TeXstudio...`, `Commands` tab, and in the `PdfLaTeX` option you will see

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

then, you need to add the options there, like

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

then, click `Ok`. And the next execution of `pdflatex` should use that option.

You should see it in the log.

Comment: I added it and still, the code from that link doesn't compile.  The error I get is:

 `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'document.pgf-plot.tab<file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. ^^I^^Iplot 'data.txt' smooth sbezier;};`

Comment: try to compile the source in a command line `pdflatex -shell-escape yourtexfile.tex` and if that gives the same error the problem is your file, and not the configuration of TeXstudio. If not, then you need to post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to reproduce your error.

Comment: Just to make sure. Do you know if you have gnuplot?