# Trying to use minted package and getting error "Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag."

Tags: packages, miktex, texstudio, minted

*I am using Windows 8.1, MiKTeX 2.9, TeXstudio. Everything including packages are fully updated.*

I am trying to compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

And getting this error:

[image]

---

**Question:** What to do?

---

Comment: as the error message says, you need `pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile.tex` not `pdflatex yourfile.tex`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How to do that on Windows?

Comment: well I tend to use the commandline so I would just type what I wrote. If you ask how to configure texstudio I do not know I don't have that editor, but it may have an option already

Comment: a simple site search suggests https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358289/texstudio-compile-using-shell