# PGF plot to match excel plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to get a plot using `pgfplots` to match an excel plot:[image] but with the x-axis numbers horizontal and labeled at the major grids of 0, 50, 100, 150, ... 400.

With the current code, my plot looks like this:

[image]

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
0   0.102
1   0.099
2   0.067
3   0.021
4   0.002
5   0.000
6   0.000
7   0.000
8   0.000
9   0.000
10  0.000
11  0.000
12  0.000
13  0.000
14  0.000
15  0.000
16  0.000
17  0.000
18  0.000
19  0.000
20  0.000
21  0.000
22  0.000
23  0.000
24  0.000
25  0.000
26  0.000
27  0.000
28  0.000
29  0.000
30  0.000
31  0.000
32  0.000
33  0.000
34  0.000
35  0.000
36  0.000
37  0.000
38  0.000
39  0.000
40  0.000
41  0.000
42  0.000
43  0.000
44  0.000
45  0.000
46  0.000
47  0.000
48  0.000
49  0.000
50  0.000
51  0.000
52  0.000
53  0.000
54  0.000
55  0.000
56  0.000
57  0.000
58  0.000
59  0.001
60  0.001
61  0.001
62  0.001
63  0.001
64  0.000
65  0.000
66  0.000
67  0.000
68  0.000
69  0.000
70  0.000
71  0.000
72  0.000
73  0.000
74  0.000
75  0.000
76  0.000
77  0.000
78  0.000
79  0.000
80  0.000
81  0.000
82  0.000
83  0.000
84  0.000
85  0.000
86  0.000
87  0.000
88  0.000
89  0.000
90  0.000
91  0.000
92  0.000
93  0.000
94  0.000
95  0.000
96  0.000
97  0.000
98  0.000
99  0.000
100 0.000
101 0.000
102 0.000
103 0.000
104 0.000
105 0.000
106 0.000
107 0.000
108 0.000
109 0.000
110 0.000
111 0.000
112 0.001
113 0.001
114 0.001
115 0.001
116 0.000
117 0.000
118 0.001
119 0.001
120 0.001
121 0.001
122 0.001
123 0.000
124 0.000
125 0.000
126 0.000
127 0.000
128 0.000
129 0.000
130 0.000
131 0.000
132 0.000
133 0.000
134 0.000
135 0.000
136 0.001
137 0.001
138 0.000
139 0.000
140 0.000
141 0.000
142 0.000
143 0.001
144 0.001
145 0.001
146 0.000
147 0.000
148 0.000
149 0.000
150 0.000
151 0.000
152 0.001
153 0.001
154 0.000
155 0.000
156 0.000
157 0.000
158 0.000
159 0.000
160 0.000
161 0.001
162 0.001
163 0.001
164 0.000
165 0.000
166 0.000
167 0.000
168 0.000
169 0.000
170 0.001
171 0.001
172 0.001
173 0.001
174 0.000
175 0.000
176 0.000
177 0.001
178 0.002
179 0.002
180 0.002
181 0.002
182 0.002
183 0.001
184 0.000
185 0.001
186 0.001
187 0.001
188 0.001
189 0.001
190 0.001
191 0.000
192 0.000
193 0.000
194 0.000
195 0.001
196 0.001
197 0.001
198 0.001
199 0.001
200 0.001
201 0.001
202 0.000
203 0.000
204 0.001
205 0.001
206 0.001
207 0.001
208 0.001
209 0.001
210 0.001
211 0.001
212 0.001
213 0.000
214 0.000
215 0.000
216 0.000
217 0.001
218 0.001
219 0.001
220 0.000
221 0.000
222 0.000
223 0.000
224 0.000
225 0.000
226 0.000
227 0.001
228 0.001
229 0.001
230 0.001
231 0.001
232 0.001
233 0.000
234 0.001
235 0.001
236 0.001
237 0.001
238 0.001
239 0.001
240 0.001
241 0.001
242 0.000
243 0.000
244 0.000
245 0.000
246 0.000
247 0.000
248 0.000
249 0.000
250 0.000
251 0.000
252 0.000
253 0.000
254 0.001
255 0.000
256 0.000
257 0.000
258 0.000
259 0.000
260 0.000
261 0.000
262 0.000
263 0.000
264 0.000
265 0.000
266 0.000
267 0.000
268 0.000
269 0.000
270 0.000
271 0.000
272 0.000
273 0.000
274 0.000
275 0.000
276 0.000
277 0.000
278 0.000
279 0.000
280 0.000
281 0.001
282 0.001
283 0.001
284 0.001
285 0.000
286 0.001
287 0.001
288 0.000
289 0.000
290 0.000
291 0.000
292 0.000
293 0.000
294 0.000
295 0.000
296 0.001
297 0.002
298 0.006
299 0.009
300 0.009
301 0.008
302 0.006
303 0.002
304 0.000
305 0.000
306 0.000
307 0.000
308 0.000
309 0.000
310 0.000
311 0.000
312 0.001
313 0.001
314 0.001
315 0.000
316 0.000
317 0.000
318 0.000
319 0.000
320 0.001
321 0.000
322 0.000
323 0.000
324 0.001
325 0.001
326 0.001
327 0.001
328 0.001
329 0.001
330 0.000
331 0.000
332 0.000
333 0.000
334 0.000
335 0.000
336 0.001
337 0.001
338 0.001
339 0.000
340 0.000
341 0.000
342 0.000
343 0.001
344 0.001
345 0.001
346 0.001
347 0.001
348 0.001
349 0.001
350 0.001
351 0.001
352 0.000
353 0.000
354 0.000
355 0.000
356 0.000
357 0.000
358 0.001
359 0.001
360 0.001
361 0.001
362 0.001
363 0.001
364 0.000
365 0.001
366 0.001
367 0.000
368 0.000
369 0.000
370 0.000
371 0.000
372 0.000
373 0.000
374 0.000
375 0.000
376 0.000
377 0.000
378 0.000
379 0.000
380 0.000
381 0.000
382 0.000
383 0.001
384 0.001
385 0.000
386 0.000
387 0.000
388 0.000
389 0.000
390 0.000
391 0.000
392 0.000
393 0.000
394 0.000
395 0.000
396 0.001
397 0.001
398 0.001
399 0.001
400 0.000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %ymin = 0.010,
    restrict y to domain = 0:0.01,
    no marks
]
  \addplot table [fill=violet, opacity=.3]{data1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is all controlled by keys and styles such as `xticklabel style`, and an example that rotates them can be already found on p. 23 of the pgfplots manual v1.16. However, if you want more explicit feedback, consider posting a complete code (and not just screen shots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add some keys (see the code after the very long data file). Note that you pass `fill=violet, opacity=.3` in the options of the table but you probably want to put them in the options of the `\addplot`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
0   0.102
1   0.099
2   0.067
3   0.021
4   0.002
5   0.000
6   0.000
7   0.000
8   0.000
9   0.000
10  0.000
11  0.000
12  0.000
13  0.000
14  0.000
15  0.000
16  0.000
17  0.000
18  0.000
19  0.000
20  0.000
21  0.000
22  0.000
23  0.000
24  0.000
25  0.000
26  0.000
27  0.000
28  0.000
29  0.000
30  0.000
31  0.000
32  0.000
33  0.000
34  0.000
35  0.000
36  0.000
37  0.000
38  0.000
39  0.000
40  0.000
41  0.000
42  0.000
43  0.000
44  0.000
45  0.000
46  0.000
47  0.000
48  0.000
49  0.000
50  0.000
51  0.000
52  0.000
53  0.000
54  0.000
55  0.000
56  0.000
57  0.000
58  0.000
59  0.001
60  0.001
61  0.001
62  0.001
63  0.001
64  0.000
65  0.000
66  0.000
67  0.000
68  0.000
69  0.000
70  0.000
71  0.000
72  0.000
73  0.000
74  0.000
75  0.000
76  0.000
77  0.000
78  0.000
79  0.000
80  0.000
81  0.000
82  0.000
83  0.000
84  0.000
85  0.000
86  0.000
87  0.000
88  0.000
89  0.000
90  0.000
91  0.000
92  0.000
93  0.000
94  0.000
95  0.000
96  0.000
97  0.000
98  0.000
99  0.000
100 0.000
101 0.000
102 0.000
103 0.000
104 0.000
105 0.000
106 0.000
107 0.000
108 0.000
109 0.000
110 0.000
111 0.000
112 0.001
113 0.001
114 0.001
115 0.001
116 0.000
117 0.000
118 0.001
119 0.001
120 0.001
121 0.001
122 0.001
123 0.000
124 0.000
125 0.000
126 0.000
127 0.000
128 0.000
129 0.000
130 0.000
131 0.000
132 0.000
133 0.000
134 0.000
135 0.000
136 0.001
137 0.001
138 0.000
139 0.000
140 0.000
141 0.000
142 0.000
143 0.001
144 0.001
145 0.001
146 0.000
147 0.000
148 0.000
149 0.000
150 0.000
151 0.000
152 0.001
153 0.001
154 0.000
155 0.000
156 0.000
157 0.000
158 0.000
159 0.000
160 0.000
161 0.001
162 0.001
163 0.001
164 0.000
165 0.000
166 0.000
167 0.000
168 0.000
169 0.000
170 0.001
171 0.001
172 0.001
173 0.001
174 0.000
175 0.000
176 0.000
177 0.001
178 0.002
179 0.002
180 0.002
181 0.002
182 0.002
183 0.001
184 0.000
185 0.001
186 0.001
187 0.001
188 0.001
189 0.001
190 0.001
191 0.000
192 0.000
193 0.000
194 0.000
195 0.001
196 0.001
197 0.001
198 0.001
199 0.001
200 0.001
201 0.001
202 0.000
203 0.000
204 0.001
205 0.001
206 0.001
207 0.001
208 0.001
209 0.001
210 0.001
211 0.001
212 0.001
213 0.000
214 0.000
215 0.000
216 0.000
217 0.001
218 0.001
219 0.001
220 0.000
221 0.000
222 0.000
223 0.000
224 0.000
225 0.000
226 0.000
227 0.001
228 0.001
229 0.001
230 0.001
231 0.001
232 0.001
233 0.000
234 0.001
235 0.001
236 0.001
237 0.001
238 0.001
239 0.001
240 0.001
241 0.001
242 0.000
243 0.000
244 0.000
245 0.000
246 0.000
247 0.000
248 0.000
249 0.000
250 0.000
251 0.000
252 0.000
253 0.000
254 0.001
255 0.000
256 0.000
257 0.000
258 0.000
259 0.000
260 0.000
261 0.000
262 0.000
263 0.000
264 0.000
265 0.000
266 0.000
267 0.000
268 0.000
269 0.000
270 0.000
271 0.000
272 0.000
273 0.000
274 0.000
275 0.000
276 0.000
277 0.000
278 0.000
279 0.000
280 0.000
281 0.001
282 0.001
283 0.001
284 0.001
285 0.000
286 0.001
287 0.001
288 0.000
289 0.000
290 0.000
291 0.000
292 0.000
293 0.000
294 0.000
295 0.000
296 0.001
297 0.002
298 0.006
299 0.009
300 0.009
301 0.008
302 0.006
303 0.002
304 0.000
305 0.000
306 0.000
307 0.000
308 0.000
309 0.000
310 0.000
311 0.000
312 0.001
313 0.001
314 0.001
315 0.000
316 0.000
317 0.000
318 0.000
319 0.000
320 0.001
321 0.000
322 0.000
323 0.000
324 0.001
325 0.001
326 0.001
327 0.001
328 0.001
329 0.001
330 0.000
331 0.000
332 0.000
333 0.000
334 0.000
335 0.000
336 0.001
337 0.001
338 0.001
339 0.000
340 0.000
341 0.000
342 0.000
343 0.001
344 0.001
345 0.001
346 0.001
347 0.001
348 0.001
349 0.001
350 0.001
351 0.001
352 0.000
353 0.000
354 0.000
355 0.000
356 0.000
357 0.000
358 0.001
359 0.001
360 0.001
361 0.001
362 0.001
363 0.001
364 0.000
365 0.001
366 0.001
367 0.000
368 0.000
369 0.000
370 0.000
371 0.000
372 0.000
373 0.000
374 0.000
375 0.000
376 0.000
377 0.000
378 0.000
379 0.000
380 0.000
381 0.000
382 0.000
383 0.001
384 0.001
385 0.000
386 0.000
387 0.000
388 0.000
389 0.000
390 0.000
391 0.000
392 0.000
393 0.000
394 0.000
395 0.000
396 0.001
397 0.001
398 0.001
399 0.001
400 0.000
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,scaled y ticks=false,
    xtick={0,50,...,400}, 
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=4},
    ymax = 0.010,ymin=0,ymajorgrids,
    restrict y to domain = 0:0.01,
    no marks,
    axis line style={draw=none},
]
  \addplot[fill=violet, opacity=.3] table {data1.dat} -- (0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  Is there a way to "smooth" out the peaks?  For some reason the excel plot shows up smoothed out as compared to the `pgfolot`.  Also, I'm not sure why the low y-axis values do not show up like in the excel plot? Thanks!

Comment: @Joe You *can* add `smooth` (or perhaps somewhat better `smooth,tension=0.2`) to `\addplot`, i.e. `\addplot[fill=violet, opacity=.3,smooth,tension=0.2]  ...`. However, this does not really do justice to the data. There is the option to use `gnuplot`, see    https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109468.